# Boolean Variable in TKinter 8.5

Tags: python, tkinter

I did this inside the python shell:

```
from Tkinter import *

v = BooleanVar()
```

But I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#52>", line 1, in <module>
    v = BooleanVar()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 320, in __init__
    Variable.__init__(self, master, value, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 185, in __init__
    self._tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tk'
>>>
```

And then while just playing around trying to make it work I tried this:

```
v = BooleanVar
```

And this worked.

So I went on to do the next logical thing, checking if the variable has been initialised and got this:

```
>>> v
<class Tkinter.BooleanVar at 0xb6f666bc>
```

Then I tried to initialise with the value `True` and for that I used the `set` method:

```
v.set(True)
```

For which I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#63>", line 1, in <module>
    v.set(True)
TypeError: unbound method set() must be called with BooleanVar instance as first argument (got bool instance instead)
```

**What** is going on?

**Please** help me with this issue

**Goal** I want to use this as the variable associated with a check button in a menu

**specs** Linux mint 14, python 2.7, Tkinter 8.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: Call `root = tk.Tk()` first.

---

Long answer:
The line that is raising the error,

```
self._tk = master.tk
```

is failing because `master` is `None`. However, look at the code (in Tkinter.py) above this line:

```
class Variable:
    def __init__(self, master=None, value=None, name=None):

        if not master:
            master = _default_root
        ...
        self._tk = master.tk
```

If you explicitly pass a `master` widget to `BooleanVar` (which is a subclass of `Variable`) then `master` would not be `None`. Or, if `_default_root` were not `None`, then `master` would not be `None`.

---

In a normal Tkinter application, you will make a root window before making a `BooleanVar`. In that case, `tk.BooleanVar()` will not raise an error.

`root = tk.Tk()` sets the `_default_root` global variable to itself (as long as the `useTk` parameter is `True` -- which it is by default). The `_default_root` is used by `BooleanVar` as the widget's master if no master is explicitly set with `tk.BooleanVar(master)`.

So in summary, either call `root = tk.Tk()` or something similar to set the `_default_root` before calling `tk.BooleanVar()`, or pass an explicit master widget as the first argument: `tk.BooleanVar(master)`.

```
In [1]: import Tkinter as tk

In [2]: root = tk.Tk()

In [3]: x = tk.BooleanVar()

In [4]: x.set(True)

In [5]: x.get()
Out[5]: 1
```

Comment: As an update, in Python 3 using `tkinter`, `tk.BooleanVar().get()` will return `False` instead of `0` and `True` instead of `1`.

Comment: i got python 3.6.8 and i recive with .get 1 for true and 0 when false. Maybe i got older tkinter liobary?