# Why doesn't this Tkinter 'after' loop stop when I click stop?

Tags: tkinter

When 'start' is clicked, a red dot grows out of the centre of the black canvas, eventually subsuming the whole thing, using an `after` loop.

I get: `UnboundLocalError: local variable`current`referenced before assignment` when I click stop.

but I defined `current` before the loop started - I am lost.

The most import parts to our discussion are:

```
Slist = [0, 0, 0, 0, 20]

clicked_stop = BooleanVar()
clicked_stop.set(False)

current = None

def grow():
    if clicked_stop.get() == True:
        biggie.after_cancel(current)
    else:
        Snow = Slist[4]
        Object = vision.create_oval(PlanetLimits(Snow), fill="red")
        Snext = Snow + 20
        Slist.append(Snext)
        Slist.pop(0)
        current = biggie.after(500, grow)

def stop():
    clicked_stop.set(True)
```

But in the interests of full disclosure, or if you want to run the code, I enclose the whole thing below.

```
import sys
from Tkinter import *

biggie = Tk()
biggie.geometry("1000x900")
biggie.title("Planets")

def PlanetLimits(R):
    return (500-(float(R)/2), 400-(float(R)/2), 500+(float(R)/2), 400+(float(R)/2))

Slist = [0, 0, 0, 0, 20]

clicked_stop = BooleanVar()
clicked_stop.set = False

current = None

def grow():
if clicked_stop.get() == True:
    biggie.after_cancel(current)
else:
    Snow = Slist[4]
    Object = vision.create_oval(PlanetLimits(Snow), fill="red")
    Snext = Snow + 20
    Slist.append(Snext)
    Slist.pop(0)
    #print Snow
    #print clicked_stop
    current = biggie.after(500, grow)
    #print current


def stop():
    clicked_stop.set(True)

vision = Canvas(biggie, height=800, width=1000, bg="black")

vision.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan = 6)

#resetbutton = Button(biggie, text="Reset", command = Reset).grid(row=1, column=0)
gobutton = Button(biggie, text="Start Simulation", command = grow).grid(row=1, column=1)
stopbutton = Button(biggie, text="Stop Simulation", command = stop).grid(row=1, column=2)
#settingsbutton = Button(biggie, text="Settings", command = Settings).grid(row=1, column=3)
#aboutbutton = Button(biggie, text="About", command = mBox).grid(row=1, column=4)
quitbutton = Button(biggie, text="Quit", command = quit).grid(row=1, column=5)

biggie.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this block of code:

```
current = None

def grow():
    if clicked_stop.get() == True:
        biggie.after_cancel(current)
    else:
        ...
        current = biggie.after(500, grow)
```

Because you didn't declare `current` as global, by virtue of setting it to a value inside `grow` it becomes local to the `grow` function. When the first part of the if statement runs, because `current` is local and because you haven't set it to anything in the function before the if statement, you get the error.

You need to declare it as global if you plan on modifying it.

Comment: I thought something like that might be the problem, but have you seen L.Clarkson's modification (above)? It doesn't use a `global` anywhere but he managed to sort it out. Thanks and seasons greetings.

Comment: @bibblybobbly: while he gave code that works, it doesn't answer your question about why you get an error.

Comment: Thank you. I have begun using inserting a line before I define or operate on certain variables, i.e. `global variable` followed by `variable` and lots of things work much better. And I have started putting in a `object.delete(ALL)` at the beginning of functions so the canvas is 'redrawn' at each stage. Am I to understand I could simplify this by using the `move` or `coords` methods? I didn't have much luck when I tried that but I wasn't armed with the `global` knowledge. So thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.set()` incorrectly for a `BooleanVar`, you must give it a value of `True` or `False` (not a integer such a 1 which is why the TypeError is thrown): `clicked_stop.set(True)`. Looking at your code, you would have to call `grow()` from the `stop()` function if you truly want to either pause or stop the growth. Here is a useful post on `BooleanVar` in Tkinter.
[Boolean Variable in TKinter 8.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611340/boolean-variable-in-tkinter-8-5)

edit:
I fixed your code so it now pauses and plays with the buttons:

```
import sys
from Tkinter import *

biggie = Tk()
biggie.geometry("1000x900")
biggie.title("Planets")

def PlanetLimits(R):
    return (500-(float(R)/2), 400-(float(R)/2), 500+(float(R)/2), 400+(float(R)/2))

Slist = [0, 0, 0, 0, 20]

clicked_stop = BooleanVar()
clicked_stop.set(False)

current = None

def grow():
    if clicked_stop.get() == 1:
        biggie.after_cancel(0)
    else:
        Snow = Slist[4]
        Object = vision.create_oval(PlanetLimits(Snow), fill="red")
        Snext = Snow + 20
        Slist.append(Snext)
        Slist.pop(0)
##        print Snow
##        print clicked_stop
        current = biggie.after(500, grow)
##        print current

def start():
    clicked_stop.set(False)
    grow()
def stop():
    clicked_stop.set(True)
    grow()

vision = Canvas(biggie, height=500, width=1000, bg="black")

vision.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan = 6)

#resetbutton = Button(biggie, text="Reset", command = Reset).grid(row=1, column=0)
gobutton = Button(biggie, text="Start Simulation", command = start).grid(row=1, column=1)
stopbutton = Button(biggie, text="Stop Simulation", command = stop).grid(row=1, column=2)
#settingsbutton = Button(biggie, text="Settings", command = Settings).grid(row=1, column=3)
#aboutbutton = Button(biggie, text="About", command = mBox).grid(row=1, column=4)
quitbutton = Button(biggie, text="Quit", command = quit).grid(row=1, column=5)

biggie.mainloop()
```

You may want to consider with the quit function to call `biggie.destroy()` as this would close the GUI without a console prompt from IDLE

Comment: Apologies for the confusion over the 0s/1s and False/Trues. I still get an UnboundLocalError because of the `current` variable - what's the deal?

Comment: I think that is because after_cancel() cannot have a value of 0, but I am not sure... in my edit `biggie.after_cancel(0)` works....

Comment: Wow, you're right, using a 0 instead of current works. Although I can't get it to begin again, but that's another matter I think... I thought the argument to the `after_cancel` function had to be the 'event ID' of the `after` function. How come 0 always works?

Comment: oh, that is weird, on my python 2.7 macbook 2013 it starts and stops just fine....Have you put in the start() function and changed what function gobutton() calls?

Comment: my mistake, i didn't notice you had edited the code and I didn't copy and paste it directly. i'm sure your revisions work perfectly. many thanks.

Comment: while this apparently provides a working solution, it doesn't really explain the source of the error.

Comment: Your solution does not need the call to `after_cancel`, especially since you are calling it incorrectly. You can't just give it a hard-coded value of 0 (zero) and expect it to work.

Comment: Also, it gets really laggy if you leave it running for a while??? Way out of my depth here... and eventually crashes?

Comment: It gets laggy because the code creates what will eventually be an infinite number of ovals, rather than creating one oval and changing its size. Tkinter canvases are known to perform poorly with many (usually 10's of thousands) of objects.

Comment: The `current` variable is (now) useless and should be removed.  `Slist` is semi-useless and could be replaced (as a global) by `Snow`, with `global Snow` added at the top of `grow`.

Comment: I agree with the first thing you said. But the second thing doesn't work. The `Slist` stack is needed to store an initial value of size, `S`, and the `grow` loop always begins by taking the last item from the stack and operating on it. How would any of this work if I got rid of `Slist`?

Comment: The .set() function takes True or False not a number which is why the typeerror int is given. Other than that I am out of my depth. Sorry I can't be more helpful.